# how to display crystal report grouping values horizontally

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm new at Crystal Reports, but would like to know how to display grouped fields horizontally instead of stacked vertically.

Currently I'm grouping on 3 different characteristics of `Mutual Funds`.  `Asset Type(Equity)`, then `Style(specific fund name)` and `Type (Managed Account/Inst Accounts)`.

For the last group `(Type)`, I'd like to have the values displayed horizontally instead of vertically, but I cannot find a way to accomplish this.

Any help would be appreciated.
![screen shot][1]

Answer (score 0):

`Screenshot is not visible try to add so that you can get more accurate answers.`

Use cross tab for last group `Type` so that you can get data horizontally..